# Navigation elements on click

Tags: android

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private AppBarConfiguration mAppBarConfiguration;
    Fragment fragment = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_gallery,
                R.id.nav_tools, R.id.nav_share)
                .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
                .build();
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, mAppBarConfiguration)
                || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
    }

}
```

I want to implement on click methods to some of my elements in nav view but if I use the following code it doesn't change the title in action bar and it is not consistent can anyone suggest a better way of setting on click listeners for the drawer. I am using the navigation drawer version 2.2.0

```
 navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                if (item.getItemId() == R.id.nav_blog) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Blog.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                if (item.getItemId() == R.id.nav_logout){
                    FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,StartActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    finish();
                }
                if (item.getItemId() == R.id.nav_settings){
                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Settings.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
                if (item.getItemId() ==R.id.nav_home){
                    fragment = new HomeFragment();
                }
                if (item.getItemId() ==R.id.nav_gallery){
                    fragment = new GalleryFragment();
                }
                if (item.getItemId() ==R.id.nav_tools){
                    fragment = new ToolsFragment();
                }
                if (item.getItemId() ==R.id.nav_cal){
                    fragment = new CalenderFragment();
                }
                FragmentManager fragmentManager =
                        getSupportFragmentManager();

                fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment, fragment)
                        .commit();
                DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
                drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation would be to use Android Annotations. To do so, simply add the following lines to your build.gradle

```
    repositories {
        maven {
            url = 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots'
        }
    }

    def AASnapshotVersion = '4.7.0-SNAPSHOT'

    dependencies {
        annotationProcessor "org.androidannotations:androidannotations:$AASnapshotVersion"
        implementation "org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:$AASnapshotVersion"
    }
```

You can now annotate a function with @Click(R.id.nav_home) for exemple to specify that it is an onClickListener.

For more information on AA, you can check their website http://androidannotations.org/ which will direct you to their git page